# Is it possible to keep workspace on Amazon EC2 server between runs?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins, continuous-integration, teamcity, virtualenv

We develop a software for Linux and Mac using C++ and python. So far we have installed all required packages into virtualenv using pip. Now 3rdParty libraries take substantial amount of time to compile. We want to speed up build process on the build servers.

**One way is not to wipe out build agent workspace between builds. Is it possible when using Amazon EC2 servers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Jenkins plugin can be used to copy files into the slave workspace.

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

After you can get instance to its base state, you can use that to create an AMI. Now if you launch with that AMI in the future, all the libraries should be in place. At that point you can do any additional bootstrapping you need.

It will use your existing key unless you prep the instance before creating an AMI to use the key provided at launch.

Comment: Do I get this right? The only way to store dependencies is to bake AMI with them. Any files bootstrapped after booting will be wiped out.

Comment: If you stop an instance, technically it will keep the same state, when you restart it. This is only valid for EBS backed instances. But if you want to launch a new instance with the dependencies already installed, you need to use an AMI.